# Submitting a post that belongs to current user - how to define the relation on client-side in Vue?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, sequelize.js, vuex

Im building an app using Node.js, specifically Express server-side and Vue client-side, with SQLite + Sequelize for managing the database.

Part of the functionality is that a user can make a post. This is currently possible but I needed to implement a relation so a post can be associated with the author.

I did this server-side in sequelize and all seems to be well on that end as the table columns all look correct with foreign key and references etc.

So now I need to somehow presumably set the current `UserId` for the post before it gets submitted. Here is the script element for the Vue component which is to be used as the interface to make posts.

```
<script>
import PostService from '@/services/PostService'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            post: {
                title: null,
                body: null
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async submit () {
            try {
                await PostService.post(this.post)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.response.data.error)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm using Vuex to manage the state, where the 'user' object response from the database upon login is stored as simply `user` in my store.

So I was guessing all I had to do was the following to access the user:

```
post: {
    title: null,
    body: null
    UserId: this.$store.state.user.id
}
```

The problem is any time I insert this line, the component stops working in some way. Doing as above stops the component displaying at all. So I tried setting it to null as default, then instead doing this inside my `submit` method:

```
this.post.UserId = this.$store.state.user.id
```

If I do this, the component displays but the submit method no longer runs; I also tried both these methods without the `.id` just incase, no difference.

I then tried removed from the data model completely, after reading that sequelize may be generating a `setUser` method for my post model. So tried the following in `submit` method before sending the post:

```
this.post.setUser(this.$store.state.user)
```

... again the method stops running. Again, even if adding `.id`.

Without trying to set any ID at all, everything works until the server returns an error that 'Post.UserID cannot be null', and everything worked perfectly before I implemented the relation.

I haven't really found anything useful beyond what I already tried from doing a few searches. Can anyone help out? I'm totally new to Node.

I have accessed other parts of the state such as `isUserLoggedIn`, and it all works fine and no crashes occur in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to get it working correctly, I'm not sure why it suddenly started working as I am sure I had tried this before, but I solved it by doing the following within my component's script element:

```
<script>
import PostService from '@/services/PostService'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            post: {
                title: null,
                body: null,
                UserId: null
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async submit () {
            this.post.UserId = this.$store.state.user.id

            try {
                await PostService.post(this.post)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.response.data.error)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Posts now create and display as normal. If anyone knows anything I'm technicially not doing right in any of my approach though please let me know, as I am still learning Node, Express and Vue.